# Android Intent Filter for Non-registered File Extension

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to set up an intent filter so that the Downloads app (in Kit Kat) will open my application when a file with the appropriate extension is selected.

The file extension does not have an associated MIME type in the Android world.

I can get my app to trigger on HTTP download based on the scheme and MIME type offered by the web server.  And I can use a file manager just fine based off of extension.  But not the Downloads app.  The file manager list my app as handling the file type and allows me to choose it to open the file.  The Downloads app just toasts "can't open file".

What is required to make this work?

Comment: What exactly happens when you click on your file in the Downloads app? Can you get some logs as to see what the system is trying to do i.e launch what app with what intents? That might give some clue. Have you seen Downloads app ever launch a chooser if there are multiple apps that can respond to it's intent?

Comment: That was a great hint.  It let me see exactly what I needed to set configure the intent filter.  The key bit was setting the category (DEFAULT & BROWSABLE), the scheme to "content", and setting the mime type returned by the web server -- and nothing else.